# PHP doesn't work after upgrading Ubuntu 17.10 to 18.04

Tags: 18.04, php

I just upgraded my Ubuntu 17.10 to 18.04 and php stopped working. I restarted apache and tried some solutions I found on the web such as

```
sudo a2enmod php7.1
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

but still it doesn't work.

```
$ journalctl -xe -u apache2

-- Unit apache2.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is RESULT.
-- Reboot --
Nis 29 02:31:21 hasan systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
-- Subject: Unit apache2.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit apache2.service has begun starting up.
Nis 29 02:31:28 hasan apachectl[947]: apache2: Syntax error on line 146 of /etc/
Nis 29 02:31:28 hasan apachectl[947]: Action 'start' failed.
Nis 29 02:31:28 hasan apachectl[947]: The Apache error log may have more informa
Nis 29 02:31:28 hasan systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=
Nis 29 02:31:28 hasan systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code
Nis 29 02:31:28 hasan systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
-- Subject: Unit apache2.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit apache2.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is RESULT.
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: what does `journalctl -xe -u apache2` say?

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen I edited my question

Comment: Please run this `apache2ctl configtest`, I see this `apache2: Syntax error on line 146 of /etc/` in the journalctl logs. Please make sure nothing is left out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I reinstalled php and now it works.

> remove php completely

```
sudo apt-get --purge --autoremove php7.0 php7.0-common
```

> then reinstall php 7.0

```
 sudo apt-get install php7.0
```

Comment: could you tell us how you did that exactly? It could be helpful to others

Comment: @Zanna I just removed and reinstalled php actually, not more